# SQL - Show data from current and future months in pivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, getdate

I an new to the pivot function and I am trying to use it to create new columns with existing data. In this case the columns should be based on the data from the current month and each month for an entire year. The field `Months` contains the month in YYYYMM format.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       [Num]
      ,[Channel]
      ,[Months]
      ,[Currency]
      ,[Value]
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Decision_Details]
    WHERE 
    (Key_Name = 'Decision'
    OR Key_Name = 'LastCycle')
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Value])
    FOR [Months] IN ([201705], [201706], [201708], [201709], [201710], [201711], [201712])
)AS pvt
```

And receive the following output:

[image]

This is the correct output but I need the columns to be based on the data from current month (201705) and onward, instead of being hard-coded.

I have tried adding `LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),112),6)` to the pivot query but it doesn't seem to work the way that I want it to.

Any suggestions on how to incorporate this into my query?

**Update:**

Managed to get every month using Dynamic Pivot:

[image]

Comment: A SQL query returns fixed column names.  If you want flexible names, you will need to use dynamic SQL.  Try Googling:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I managed to solve my problem by using the following query. (Note that there is probably room for improvement here but this works for me):

```
 DECLARE @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Months) 
            FROM [Test].[dbo].[Decision_Details] c
            WHERE (Months >= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, (DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 112),6)
            AND Months <= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, (DATEADD(MONTH, +6, GETDATE())), 112),6))
            AND Key_Name = 'Decision'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        ,1,1,'')

set @query2 = 'SELECT Num, Channel, Currency, ' + @cols2 + ' from 
            (
                select  Key_name,
                        Num, 
                        Channel, 
                        Months,
                        Currency,
                        Value
                from [Test].[dbo].[Decision_Details]
                WHERE (Months >= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, (DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 112),6)
                AND Months <= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, (DATEADD(MONTH, +6, GETDATE())), 112),6))
                AND Key_Name = ''Decision''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 MAX([Value])
                for Months in (' + @cols2 + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query2)
```

[image]